# Changing a div style in wordpress when it change to another page?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Hi this is my first question here. So I am new here.
I am trying to change the margin-top of a div in a wordpress when it goes to another page.
Here is my code I put them in header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#mycontentdiv").each(function() { 
        if (this.href == window.location.href) {
            $(this).addClass("classmargintop");
        }<br>
    });
</script>

<?php
   if ( is_front_page() != is_page('contact-us')){
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
   , 'thisfunctionofme();'
   , '</script>';
}
?>
```

is my conditional correct? I just based it in some codes in wordpress, and the javascript code I just see it here. I hope someone can help me thanks.

Comment: What is that `<br>` doing there? It will produce a Syntax Error.

Comment: You are looping through elements with **ID** `mycontentdiv` but you should only have one element with this ID as IDs are unique. If you have multiple divs on the page which need the margin applied you should use a class instead of an ID.

Comment: Can you clarify, are you navigating to a new page or do you mean a new section on the same page, so the second, third etc `<div>` on the page. If the latter you can do this with CSS selectors instead of JS.